# Show notification Form at NotifyIcon's position as Dropbox

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

I am writting an application that uses NotifyIcon in C#. I want when user clicks on the NotifyIcon on the system tray (bottom-right of the screen) a notification form (this is not the mainform, it's only a minor form that is used to show notification) will show up at the location of NotifyIcon as Dropbox do: [image]

I have used the event MouseClick of NotifyIcon and wrote as follows:

```
private void NotifyIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    form.SetDesktopLocation(MousePosition.X - form.Width/2,MousePosition.Y-form.Height-20);
    form.Show();
    form.Focus();
 }
```

but it does not work as expected, the notification form show up at the location of main form not at the location of NotifyIcon.

can anybody can help me:|

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Form2` design, select properties of `Form2`. Look for `StartPosition` in properties of `Form2`, set `StartPosition` as `Manual` or you can do it as

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
form.SetDesktopLocation(MousePosition.X - form.Width/2,MousePosition.Y-form.Height-20);
form.Show();
form.Focus();
```

Hope this you solve your issue.